# How to navigate to a child state using parameters from a factory using Angular.js and ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router, angularjs-factory

I'm trying to get angular ui-router to navigate to a child state using a parameter supplied by a factory which has a default parameter at the start in order to preserve the parameters across the app.

I would like the default home page and that link to go to a default animal provided by a factory upon initial load, and then the user can update the animal and the parameters when selecting an animal from the list which gets preserved by the factory so when they navigate back to the animals page it is now instead their chosen animal with all that animals parameters instead of the default. That way if they go to say the veterinarian page, the veterinarian page can check all the chosen animal parameters and when they return to the animal page it's the chosen animal whether they click on the back button or the animals link. Please excuse the silly metaphors.

app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp, ['ui.router'])
   .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider
         .when('zoo', ['animals', function(animals) {
            $state.go('zoo.animals.animal', animals.Params);
          }])
      $stateProvider
         .state('zoo', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/zoo',
            controller: 'ZooCtrl',
            view: '<ui-view/>'
            resolve: {
               zoo: function(zoo) {
                  return zoo;
               }
            }
         })
     .state('zoo.animals', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/animals',
        view: '<ui-view/>'
        controller: 'AnimalsCtrl'
      })
      .state('zoo.animals.animal', {
          url: '/:animalId',
          view: 'views/zoo.animals.animal.html'
      })
  })
```

animals.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .factory('animals', ['zoo', function(zoo) {
      var zoo = zoo;
      var Default = {};
      Default.animalId = 'sheep';
      Default.color = 'black';
      var Params = angular.copy(Default);
      var animal;
      return: {
      Params: Params,
      list: zoo.animals,
      animal: animal
    }
}])
```

zoo.js -- factory

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .factory('zoo', ['$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resouce('http://zoo.com/info', {
         method: 'GET',
         isArray: true 
      });
   }])
```

zoo.js -- controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .controller('ZooCtrl', ['$scope', 'animals','function($scope, zoo) {
      $scope.animals = animals.list;
      $scope.setAnimal = function(animal) {
      animals.animal = animal;
      animals.Params.animalId = animal.animalId;
    }
}])
```

zoo.animals.animal.html

```
<h2>Default animal{{animal.name}}</h2>
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="animal in zoo.animals"><a ng-click="setAnimal(animal)" ui-sref="/zoo/animals/{{animal.animalId}}">animal.name</li>
</ul>
```

Now whether if I use this index.html

```
<a ui-sref="zoo">Animals</a>
<ui-view />
```

I get a 'can't navigate to abstract state' - fine.
But if I try this index.html

```
<a ui-sref="zoo.animals.animal">Animals</a>
<ui-view />
```

Then it just goes to

```
localhost:8000/myapp/#/zoo/animals
```

without getting the animalId provided. 
Or if I navigate away from it and back it's gone.
I hope it makes sense what I'm trying to accomplish.

Edit: A step closer!
If I change the index.html link to

```
<a href="#/zoo">Animals</a>
```

and the app.js when attribute to:

```
$urlprovider
   .when('/zoo', ['$state', 'animals', function($state, animals){
      $state.go('zoo.animals.animal', animals.Params);
   }])
```

Then it does navigate to

```
localhost:8000/#/zoo/animals/sheep
```

or

```
localhost:8000/#/zoo/animals/wolf
```

if wolf is selected whether using the back arrow or Animals link from another page.
Or if refreshed it goes to the default animals (sheep) page.
But now if you are on the

```
localhostL8000/#/zoo/animals/sheep
```

page and click on Animals link it goes to

```
localhost:8000/#/zoo/animals
```

(Still there's another strange occurrence,  in that the data is loaded and there in the factory but won't display until it is chosen from the select list.)